# NO POWER after shorting (2) hots of a multi-wire circuit in 3-switch indoor jbox

Tags: electrical

the goal was to swap smart switch for exterior lites with standard switch and dusk-to-dawn lite bulbs.  I turned on entry light to identify when I had correct breaker turned off.  While working in the box I felt current on my hand and then that the power on that leg was gone.  This jbox has (3) lite switches; (2) powered by a red + black hot wrapped by black neutral (1) powered by black and neutral.  There is another hot powering outlet, smoke detector and garage lites and outlets.

Summary:  I shorted out (1) red/black hot (no power now to exterior lites) then I shorted another hot (no power now to outlet and garage lites and doors) but, still power on (1) lite switch (entry hall lites).  NO TRIPPED BREAKERS; reset each 120V breaker.

What did I do ??  How do I resolve ?

Thanks very much,
Dan

Comment: Hire an electrician.

Comment: **Pictures of junction box and breaker panel would help.** Very confusing. You may have multiple circuits in one box. *wrapped by black neutral* sounds very strange, as neutral should never be black (but in certain cases a hot can be white). An ordinary (not smart) switch will have hot & switched hot but no neutral. A smart switch will (typically) have hot, switched hot and neutral. Hot and switched hot are *usually* black or red, but in certain cases hot can legitimately be white.

Comment: Sounds like you probably tripped a GFI.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I'm guessing the white wire is correctly wrapped with black tape and is thus an unswitched hot in a switch loop, but being incorrectly described as `wrapped by black neutral ` under the mistaken belief that white is always neutral.

Comment: And Dan - next time, use a voltmeter with nice insulated probes (or use a non-contact tester if you believe in those) on ***everything*** in the box before you dive in and start touching things. You didn't get killed - this time. That was luck. Don't push yours. You should also read up a bit so you understand what a switch loop white hot is, why you might have one (legally in things built before NEC 2011(?), illegally after that point) and understand what you are getting into before you dive in and risk killing yourself, setting your house on fire, etc...

Comment: @Ecnerwal   good advice, but I bristle when ppl here say, you're lucky you didn't get killed.   I've been shocked many times and at 66yo I'm still here.  While possible, it's unlikely to get killed by a shock. I understand why some ppl here will advocate for an "extreme of caution", I get that.   But this isn't Plutonium.   A few days ago I was working on my sons house, his job was to replace outlets that were backstapped and 40 years old. He turned off most of the breakers and then turned them back on, INCLUDING the 240 v breaker to an HP disconnect.  ...continued below....

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson It's a chance Every. Single. Time. If you get overconfident because you haven't yet hit the wrong combination of factors, that can have bad side effects on your odds.

Comment: I was doing the final wiring in the disconnect that I assumed (stupid on my part not to double check) that it was still turned off. So I was being pretty casual, thinking the power was off. It was a hot day and my hands where sweaty, making for a great conductor, and bumped into the feed lugs.  Got a pretty decent zap, left a small burn mark on the backside of my hand.  The upshot of this lengthy comment is that electrocution when working on live circuits is very uncommon.   What's really important is proper grounding on things like swimming pools and hot tubs.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Glad you survived! Of course, this is the basis for lockouts, local disconnects, etc. Which in a typical single family home situation are generally irrelevant - one electrician working at a time, everyone else knows "don't touch the panel". But you just proved why those rules (generally ignored in terms of tagging/locking out a breaker) exist.